# Curve fitting - linear vs non-linear

Tags: r, curve-fitting, lm, nls

```
Dose       Survival
1.044316   0.7085001
2.017041   0.2764831
3.042148   0.1498388
4.058954   0.0451514
5.098904   0.0145274
```

I have two models to fit the data: the exact model and an approximative one:

```
exactrepair <- function(x, q2, r, p2) { (1+q2*x*(1+p2/q2*r)+x^2*q2^2*(0.5*r+p2/q2*r)+x^3*q2^3*r^2*p2/q2*0.5)*exp(-(1+p2/q2)*q2*x) }
model.repair <- nlsLM(y ~ exactrepair(x, q2, r, p2), data = ds ,start = list(q2 = 1, p2 = 1, r = 1), trace = T, alg = "port", lower= c(0,0,0), upper = c(1,1,1), weights = 1/exp(y))
```

And the approximative one:

```
aprox <- function(x, a, b) {  exp(-a*x-b*x^2) }
model.lq <- nlsLM(y ~ aprox(x, a, b), data = ds ,start = list(a = 0.42, b = 0.080), trace = T, alg = "port", lower= c(0,0), upper = c(Inf,Inf), weights = 1/exp(y))
```

I plotted both the exact and the approximated fits to the data (in red and green respectively).

[image]

Now if I take the log of the approx like this:

```
-In y=a*x+b*x^2
```

I can fit the data linearly:

```
aproxlin <- function(x, a, b) {  a*x + b*x^2 }
model12 <- lm(-log(c(1,y))~c(0,x))
```

If I plot the fitted values from the linear plot I get a much better fit to the data (blue line in the plot).

How can I get better values for the "exact" formula (first version)?

Comment: You might want to use weights. `nlme:::gnls` even allows specifying variance structures.

Comment: Reposting comment after migration: You plot with a log y axis. That your blue line is closer to the points means that the log-linear model fits much better to the smaller y values than to the larger values. You need to consider how the error term is modeled: see [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/254706/11849) and [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254876/regression-models-for-log-transformed-data-without-multiplicative-error/255265#255265).

Comment: I noticed something on your plot that you should consider.  Every one of the data points is above the red line for "exact", and this should not ordinarily occur when fitting an equation to the lowest sum-of-squared error.